# set an image to a qt pushbutton

Tags: qt, resources, qpixmap

I tried to set an image to a Qt pushbutton using this widely known code.

```
QPixmap *pic = new QPixmap(":/images/logo.png");
QIcon *icon = new QIcon(*pic);
ui->pushButton->setIcon(*icon);
ui->pushButton->setIconSize(QSize(pic->width(), pic->height()));
```

Here's my qrc file

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/images">
        <file>images/logo.png</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Even though the program compiles, always a runtime exception occurs at

```
QPixmap *pic = new QPixmap(":/images/logo.png");
```

When I tried printing *pic on output console, it showed that pic =  QPixmap(QSize(0, 0) ). i.e. it is null. Any ideas as to where I went wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please don't use pointers there.

You don't even have to create a `QPixmap` object and then use that to create a `QIcon` object. [QIcon has a constructor](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qicon.html#QIcon-4) that takes a file name as a parameter. But that's up to you. Also check your resource location. It looks like it should be `:/images/images/logo.png`

```
QPixmap pix(":/images/images/logo.png");
QIcon icon(pix);
ui->pushButton->setIcon(icon);
ui->pushButton->setIconSize(pix.size())
```

Comment: ah yes! didn't think of that constructor. Anyway, I modified my code. Now QPixmap object gets initialized fine. But still the program crashes at QIcon icon(pic); why would that be?

Comment: @Lizzie If you create an empty pixmap does it still crash? `QPixmap pic;` `QIcon icon(pic);`

Comment: yes it still does. It is similar to my earlier problem where pic is actually empty, isn't it?

Comment: @Lizzie Yes, but it shouldn't cause a crash. Are you sure that it's `QIcon icon(pic);` that causes the crash?

Comment: sorry! my bad. It's actually at this line. ui->pushButton->setIcon(icon);

Comment: @Lizzie Are you doing this before the `ui->setupUi(this);` line? Cause if you are, then `ui->pushButton` is not an initialized object.

Comment: Yes! that was the problem! thanks @thuga. I'll mark this as the correct answer :)

Answer (score 3):

If you use an alias in your resource definition, using the resource is a little easier: -

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/images">
        <file>images/logo.png</file>
        <file alias="logo">images/logo.png</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Then you can reference the resource via its alias and if you change the image in the resource, you won't need to change the code: -

```
QPixmap image(":/images/logo");
QPushButton* pPushButton = new QPushButton(QIcon(image));
```

Or if the button is already defined: -

```
pPushButton->setIcon(QIcon(image));
```

Answer (score 1):

Is your Resource properly initialized? You might try this: (from the [docs](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/resources.html))

> If you have resources in a static library, you might need to force
>   initialization of your resources by calling Q_INIT_RESOURCE() with the
>   base name of the .qrc file. For example:

```
 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
     QApplication app(argc, argv);
     Q_INIT_RESOURCE(graphlib);
     ...
     return app.exec();
 }
```

***EDIT***
More important:

QPixmap assumes a 'images' prefix. Try `QPixmap(":/logo.png");`

Answer (score 1):

I think you should call:

```
QPixmap *pic = new QPixmap(":/images/images/logo.png");
```

because you already set the prefix `/images`.

Comment: Thanks! I modified it. But still the code crashes at QIcon *icon = new QIcon(*pic);

Comment: it crashes actually at ui->pushButton->setIcon(*icon);